# Dynamically rendering a list consisting of material icons and custom SVG Icons

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have defined menu items in the sidebar as shown below and I intend to add a new custom SVG icon. Looking at my current implementation, I can render the material icons as expected but now the challenge comes in when I include the new custom SVG icon it's not rendering.

In the `side-bar-component.html` you will see that I'm iterating over the list of icons and rendering them dynamically.

I added the `MatIconRegistry` service in `app.component.ts` and imported the `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts`. I'm required to add `svgIcon` into `mat-icon` in this format `<mat-icon svgIcon=“license_certificate”></mat-icon>` to render the SVG icon, but the rest of the icons are material icons they don't require this. How can I dynamically add `svgIcon=“license_certificate` and render the icon?

**Sidebar**

[image]

**side-bar-component.ts**

```
    menu = [
        {
          path: '/dashboard',
          icon: 'home',
          name: 'Home'
        },
        {
          icon: 'local_drink',
          name: 'Liquor',
          perm: 'liquor',
          children: [
            {
              path: '/applications',
              icon: 'assignment',
              name: 'Applications'
            },
            {
              path: '/renewals',
              icon: 'autorenew',
              name: 'Renewals'
            },
            {
              path: '/license/issue',
              icon: 'license_certificate', // CUSTOM ICON
              name: 'Issue'
            },
            {
              path: '/activities',
              icon: 'business_center',
              name: 'Activities'
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Billing',
          icon: 'receipt',
          perm: 'billing',
          children: [
            {
              path: '/billing/list',
              icon: 'history',
              name: 'Billing History'
            },
            {
              path: '/billing/search',
              icon: 'search',
              name: 'Search Bills'
            }
          ]
        },

        {
          name: 'Receipting',
          icon: 'receipt',
          perm: 'receipting',
          children: [
            {
              path: '/receipting/add',
              icon: 'note_add',
              name: 'New Receipt'
            },
            {
              path: '/receipting/list',
              icon: 'history',
              name: 'Receipt List'
            },
            {
              path: '/receipting/search',
              icon: 'search',
              name: 'Search'
            }

          ]
        }]


  ngOnInit() {
    const perms = ['sbp', 'liquor', 'billing', 'receipting'];
    perms.push('None');
    perms.push('sbp');
    console.log(perms);
    // perms = perms.split(',')

    this.menu = this.menu.filter(item => perms.some(f => f.toLowerCase() === item.perm)
    );

  }
```

**side-bar-component.html**

For the SVG to render it is expected that `mat-icon` to have `svgIcon="nameOfIcon` this doesn't apply with the rest of the icons.

```
<mat-accordion>
   <li *ngFor="let item of menu" class="row" [ngClass]="{active: isActive(item)}">
   <div class="row parent-item" [routerLink]="item.path" *ngIf="!item.children">
   <mat-icon>{{item.icon}}</mat-icon>
   <span>{{item.name}}</span>
   </div>
   </li>
</mat-accordion>
```

**app.module.ts**

I've imported the `HttpClientModule` as expected in `app.module.ts`

```
.....
  imports: [
    AppCommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
....
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      `license_certificate`,
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('../assets/images/icons/license_certificate.svg')
    );
  }
}
```

**Image Directory**

[image]

Comment: Can you validate that your path is correct? And could you try './assets/images/...'.

Comment: @SebastianMünster The path is correct it should be  `../assets/images/icons/license_certificate.svg`

Comment: Yes, in your dev directory. But in the builded version the assets folder is located in the root.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new field to your model

```
path: '/dashboard',
icon: 'home',
name: 'Home',
isCustom: true,
```

(Not this one obviously, that's just an example)

In your HTML :

```
<mat-icon [svgIcon]="item.isCustom && name || ''">{{ !item.isCustom && item.icon || '' }}</mat-icon>
```

Comment: Why do we have an empty string after or ` || ` ?

Comment: @PhilipMutua to display an empty string ! if you don't, it will display `undefined`, which will then be interpreted as a SVG/matIcon string

Comment: ok got it still  I can't render the image let me check the path.